# Create a query to remove rows with a 0 value

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I'm sure this is probably a simple answer but I can't work out where I'm going wrong.  I have a data table that I've copied to a new tab from (ForMaster!A511:G574).  It brings in 7 columns data, the last 2 columns containing numerical values.

Sample Doc
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zcIHvSM1V_rVH8uiRE1ZhQHkptJLLlw9gnumSurZOps/edit?usp=sharing

I've been trying to set up a query that would look at columns F & G and remove rows where there is a zero in both columns.  Ultimately, I want rows that have a $value in either to remain.  This is a live doc, so if a row initially has a zero, I'd like it to be visible if a value is added at a future date.

I've tried using
=QUERY({ForMaster!A511:G574},"select * where Col6 >=0 or Col7 >=0"), but it doesn't eliminate any rows.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison should be only greater than 0 to eliminate rows with both zero values.

`=QUERY({ForMaster!A511:G574},"select * where  F>0 or G>0")`

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: formula in answer will never work (fx on picture is ok)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(ForMaster!A511:G574; "where F+G <> 0"; 1)
```

[image]